# Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full on PI4 ubuntu focal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good morning,

I followed all the instructions. I have Ubuntu 20. Installed on raspberry pi4 when I run sudo apt install ros-desktop-full, I get the error above "Unable to locate package ros-noetic-full".

Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354340/unable-to-locate-package-ros-noetic-desktop-full-on-pi4-ubuntu-focal/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2020-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-08**:
What is the output of `uname -rvmp` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

Also:

> I followed all the instructions

*always* link to any instructions you followed or are referring to.

We cannot know *which* instructions you've followed, and there are many.

And I just noticed:

> when I run `sudo apt install ros-desktop-full`

that's actually not the correct package name.

> ```
> get the error above "Unable to locate package ros-noetic-full".
> ```

And neither is `ros-noetic-full`.

Please do not paraphrase errors. Copy-paste them *verbatim* into your question.

We cannot help you otherwise.

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2020-06-08**:
Good Afternoon Thank you for your response. I was following the instruction posted here: **http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu** *(Step:1.4)* with the command `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` and got the error `E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full` ....

To your follow-up question:

Output from `uname -rvmp` is :

```
5.4.0-1011-raspi #11-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 07:43:33 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64
```

Output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`  is :

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [status_page/ros_noetic_ufv8.html?q=desktop](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_ufv8.html?q=desktop), the binary packages for `arm64` of `desktop_full` are not building right now.

It is released, but the red squares indicate the binaries are *missing*, which typically means the build is failing for some reason.

A look at the [release job](http://build.ros.org/view/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8/job/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8__desktop_full__ubuntu_focal_arm64__binary/) seems to indicate that two packages which `desktop_full` depends on fail to build:

- [Nbin_ufv8_uFv8__simulators__ubuntu_focal_arm64__binary](http://build.ros.org/view/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8/job/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8__simulators__ubuntu_focal_arm64__binary/)
- [Nbin_ufv8_uFv8__urdf_sim_tutorial__ubuntu_focal_arm64__binary](http://build.ros.org/view/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8/job/Nbin_ufv8_uFv8__urdf_sim_tutorial__ubuntu_focal_arm64__binary/)

And from looking at *their* dependencies, it would seem `gazebo_ros_pkgs` and `gazebo_ros_control` isn't building on `arm64` at the moment.

I haven't checked why that is the case, but it would seem that's why ultimately `desktop_full` is not available.

If you don't absolutely need Gazebo -- and I doubt it would make sense to run Gazebo on an RPi, even a 4 -- then you could install something other than `desktop_full`, something which doesn't include the `simulators` metapackage.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2020-06-08**:
Okay  thank you. So should I guess I just have to wait for that to be functional then. Should I try back in 2 days or would it be linger than that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-08**:
Without looking at the reason for the build failure I can't say whether 2 days is enough.

If you'd like to know, I would encourage you to take a look at the issue tracker of `gazebo_ros_pkgs`. There may already be an issue open to track this.

And it will always go faster if more people help.

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2020-06-08**:
Will do. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-08**:
But you do want to run Gazebo on an RPi then?

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2020-06-08**:
I am looking to use ROS powered RPlidar borax, new territory for me..do you think I would have use for Gazebo for this?

Regards

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-09**:
Gazebo is a physics based robot simulator.

To use a rpilidar, I don't believe you'll need a simulator.

Or at least: you most likely don't need to run a simulator on your RPi.